# remove elemets from list with identical character contentin python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I have the following list

['KAK1K2', 'KAK1K3', 'KAK1K4', 'KAK1K5', 'KAK1K6', 'KAK2K1', 'KAK2K3', 'KAK2K4', 'KAK2K5', 'KAK2K6', 'KAK3K1', 'KAK3K2', 'KAK3K4', 'KAK3K5', 'KAK3K6', 'KAK4K1', 'KAK4K2', 'KAK4K3', 'KAK4K5', 'KAK4K6', 'KAK5K1', 'KAK5K2', 'KAK5K3', 'KAK5K4', 'KAK5K6', 'KAK6K1', 'KAK6K2', 'KAK6K3', 'KAK6K4', 'KAK6K5', 'K1KAK2', 'K1KAK3', 'K1KAK4', 'K1KAK5', 'K1KAK6', 'K1K2KA', 'K1K2K3', 'K1K2K4', 'K1K2K5', 'K1K2K6', 'K1K3KA', 'K1K3K2', 'K1K3K4', 'K1K3K5', 'K1K3K6', 'K1K4KA', 'K1K4K2', 'K1K4K3', 'K1K4K5', 'K1K4K6', 'K1K5KA', 'K1K5K2', 'K1K5K3', 'K1K5K4', 'K1K5K6', 'K1K6KA', 'K1K6K2', 'K1K6K3', 'K1K6K4', 'K1K6K5', 'K2KAK1', 'K2KAK3', 'K2KAK4', 'K2KAK5', 'K2KAK6', 'K2K1KA', 'K2K1K3', 'K2K1K4', 'K2K1K5', 'K2K1K6', 'K2K3KA', 'K2K3K1', 'K2K3K4', 'K2K3K5', 'K2K3K6', 'K2K4KA', 'K2K4K1', 'K2K4K3', 'K2K4K5', 'K2K4K6', 'K2K5KA', 'K2K5K1', 'K2K5K3', 'K2K5K4', 'K2K5K6', 'K2K6KA', 'K2K6K1', 'K2K6K3', 'K2K6K4', 'K2K6K5', 'K3KAK1', 'K3KAK2', 'K3KAK4', 'K3KAK5', 'K3KAK6', 'K3K1KA', 'K3K1K2', 'K3K1K4', 'K3K1K5', 'K3K1K6', 'K3K2KA', 'K3K2K1', 'K3K2K4', 'K3K2K5', 'K3K2K6', 'K3K4KA', 'K3K4K1', 'K3K4K2', 'K3K4K5', 'K3K4K6', 'K3K5KA', 'K3K5K1', 'K3K5K2', 'K3K5K4', 'K3K5K6', 'K3K6KA', 'K3K6K1', 'K3K6K2', 'K3K6K4', 'K3K6K5', 'K4KAK1', 'K4KAK2', 'K4KAK3', 'K4KAK5', 'K4KAK6', 'K4K1KA', 'K4K1K2', 'K4K1K3', 'K4K1K5', 'K4K1K6', 'K4K2KA', 'K4K2K1', 'K4K2K3', 'K4K2K5', 'K4K2K6', 'K4K3KA', 'K4K3K1', 'K4K3K2', 'K4K3K5', 'K4K3K6', 'K4K5KA', 'K4K5K1', 'K4K5K2', 'K4K5K3', 'K4K5K6', 'K4K6KA', 'K4K6K1', 'K4K6K2', 'K4K6K3', 'K4K6K5', 'K5KAK1', 'K5KAK2', 'K5KAK3', 'K5KAK4', 'K5KAK6', 'K5K1KA', 'K5K1K2', 'K5K1K3', 'K5K1K4', 'K5K1K6', 'K5K2KA', 'K5K2K1', 'K5K2K3', 'K5K2K4', 'K5K2K6', 'K5K3KA', 'K5K3K1', 'K5K3K2', 'K5K3K4', 'K5K3K6', 'K5K4KA', 'K5K4K1', 'K5K4K2', 'K5K4K3', 'K5K4K6', 'K5K6KA', 'K5K6K1', 'K5K6K2', 'K5K6K3', 'K5K6K4', 'K6KAK1', 'K6KAK2', 'K6KAK3', 'K6KAK4', 'K6KAK5', 'K6K1KA', 'K6K1K2', 'K6K1K3', 'K6K1K4', 'K6K1K5', 'K6K2KA', 'K6K2K1', 'K6K2K3', 'K6K2K4', 'K6K2K5', 'K6K3KA', 'K6K3K1', 'K6K3K2', 'K6K3K4', 'K6K3K5', 'K6K4KA', 'K6K4K1', 'K6K4K2', 'K6K4K3', 'K6K4K5', 'K6K5KA', 'K6K5K1', 'K6K5K2', 'K6K5K3', 'K6K5K4']

that was generated using this code:

```
atoms = ['KA', 'K1', 'K2','K3', 'K4', 'K5', 'K6']
combos = []

for e1 in atoms:
    for e2 in atoms:
        for e3 in atoms:
            if e1 != e2 != e3 != e1:
                combos.append(e1+e2+e3)
```

And I am willing to remove redundant elements.
For example, keep 'KAK1K2' and remove KAK2K1, 'K1KAK2', 'K1K2KA, etc.

Many thanks

Comment: You may want to look at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to memorize all `known` combinations as `frozenset` and check if you already got that one. Only add if not:

```
atoms = ['KA', 'K1', 'K2','K3', 'K4', 'K5', 'K6']
combos = []
known = set()

for e1 in atoms:
    for e2 in atoms:
        for e3 in atoms:
            if e1 != e2 != e3 != e1:
                fz = frozenset( {e1,e2,e3})
                if fz not in known:
                    known.add(fz)
                    combos.append(e1+e2+e3)
print(combos)

['KAK1K2', 'KAK1K3', 'KAK1K4', 'KAK1K5', 'KAK1K6', 'KAK2K3', 'KAK2K4', 'KAK2K5', 
'KAK2K6', 'KAK3K4', 'KAK3K5', 'KAK3K6', 'KAK4K5', 'KAK4K6', 'KAK5K6', 'K1K2K3',
'K1K2K4', 'K1K2K5', 'K1K2K6', 'K1K3K4', 'K1K3K5', 'K1K3K6', 'K1K4K5', 'K1K4K6', 
'K1K5K6', 'K2K3K4', 'K2K3K5', 'K2K3K6', 'K2K4K5', 'K2K4K6', 'K2K5K6', 'K3K4K5', 
'K3K4K6', 'K3K5K6', 'K4K5K6']
```

---

The shorter suggested way using [itertools combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) by [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) is:

```
from itertools import combinations

combos = [''.join(x) for x in combinations(atoms,3)]
print(combos) 

['KAK1K2', 'KAK1K3', 'KAK1K4', 'KAK1K5', 'KAK1K6', 'KAK2K3', 'KAK2K4', 'KAK2K5',
'KAK2K6', 'KAK3K4', 'KAK3K5', 'KAK3K6', 'KAK4K5', 'KAK4K6', 'KAK5K6', 'K1K2K3',
'K1K2K4', 'K1K2K5', 'K1K2K6', 'K1K3K4', 'K1K3K5', 'K1K3K6', 'K1K4K5', 'K1K4K6', 
'K1K5K6', 'K2K3K4', 'K2K3K5', 'K2K3K6', 'K2K4K5', 'K2K4K6', 'K2K5K6', 'K3K4K5', 
'K3K4K6', 'K3K5K6', 'K4K5K6']
```